# K - word search SQL

Tags: sql, mysql

I am attempting to write a stored procedure that can take in k words and return back the answers with the k words in them.

### word table

- word
- wordId

### description word inverted index

- descriptionID
- wordID
- count

So - given k words, how would I efficiently get all the `descriptionID`s that contain the ALL the k words?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way in a single query is to use a combination of the `IN` and `HAVING` clauses.  Example:

```
  SELECT dwi.descriptionid
    FROM DESCRIPTION_WORD_INDEX dwi
    JOIN WORD w ON w.wordid = dwi.wordid
   WHERE w.word IN ('a', 'b', 'c')
GROUP BY dwi.descriptionid
  HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT w.word) = 3
```

The number of values in the `IN` clause must match the number of distinct values counted in the `HAVING` clause.

Another means is to JOIN to multiple copies of the WORD table (in this case) for each specific word:

```
  SELECT dwi.descriptionid
    FROM DESCRIPTION_WORD_INDEX dwi
    JOIN WORD a ON a.wordid = dwi.wordid
               AND a.word = 'a'
    JOIN WORD b ON b.wordid = dwi.wordid
               AND b.word = 'b'
    JOIN WORD c ON c.wordid = dwi.wordid
               AND c.word = 'c'
```

Comment: Wow i am thoroughly impressed by that answer.  I believe you have correctly answered the question.

Comment: Now the real question is, if i have 20 million entries... how fast will that work :)

Comment: @Michael:  IIRC, the JOIN version works better with larger data sets (1,000+) -- just that it sucks to have to write :/